# an active search for methods for optimization

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-construction

> The economic situation becomes more complex in the world. So there is an active search for methods for optimization of business.

These sentences are mine. I have the feeling that the second sentence is clumsy and does not sound natural in English. I can't remember how these sentences are called in English grammar when the pronoun "it" serves as the grammatical subject followed by the verb in the present continuous tense. For example, "*it is snowing*". So I want to formulate the sentence about the active search for methods of optimization in the same way. Is it possible to use the present continous tense in such a sentence?

Comment: The sentence does not sound natural, at least to me. What troubles my eyes is 'active search' in this context. But that could be just me ;) Maybe, *'Due to the economic instability in today's world, an optimization (?) of business is needed.'* I'm still not sure using 'optimization' there. What do you want to say?

Comment: Having said that optimization is needed, you've changed the meaning of my initial sentence. I want to emphasize that the search has already started to be conducted at this moment.

Comment: Then... *"Due to the complexity of economics today, the search has already begun to make businesses optimized"* - Not sure though. That's the reason I commented but din' answer!

Comment: THanks, but that is not what I want to say. There are some ways to optimize business. So economists, financiers or whoever conduct the search for these methods. If I omit the word "methods", then readers will not be clear about what is being searched for.

Comment: It's obvious that when you *optimize* something, it includes methodology. A reader like me, who is not so good at business jargon, can easily understand this. But anyway, let others come with a special term/lingo you are looking for.

Comment: I can't answer your question because I can't think of a way for _it_ to be a subject.  However, for what it is worth, I find the following version perfectly natural, clear and precise: "The economic situation in the world is becoming more complex, so there is an active search for business optimization methods."

Comment: 1)So there is an active search <going on> for the methods  of business optimization. 2) The economic situation becomes more complex in the world. An ongoing active search for methods for optimization of business might address this issue shortly.

Comment: @Maulik VThis is not necessarily so. Methodology may not be implied in the process of searching. For example, business owners search for highly qualified system administrators for the purpose of optimising their business.

Comment: @xris I'm inclined to agree with you. To my ears, that sounds more natural too. However, I am still waiting for opinions of other native English speakers.

Comment: @CopperKettle I see. Thanks. I'll consider the possibility of using your suggestion.

Comment: Maybe you were trying to come up with something like this: *As the world economic situation becomes more complex, it is important that there be an active search for business optimization methods." or "[...] it is important that an active search for business optimization methods must be conducted." Also, you might want to consider *quest* or *research* besides *search*. And perhaps, rephrasing the sentence to use *actively* instead *of active* will sound a little better, e.g. "[...] must be actively conducted."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible rephrasing that occurs to me is...

> 1: *The global economic situation **is becoming** more complex, **leading to** an active search for business optimization methods.*

But pragmatically it seems unlikely any such "active searching" would be *directly and only **caused*** by an increasingly complex situation. It makes more sense to me to simply link *increases* in the two...

> 2: ***As*** the global economic situation **becomes** more complex, business optimization methods **are [being] more actively sought.**

I'm not sure what OP is getting at when he says he wants to use a "dummy pronoun" ***it***, but I can't help thinking maybe what he really means is he wants a [passive construction](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/passive.htm), as per my second rephrasing.

Comment: @ FumbleFingers thanks a lot. I really need a passive construction here, as per your second rephrasing. That sounds great to my female non-native ears!

Comment: @Humbulani: I'm still not clear exactly why your question refers to what we often call "dummy" **it**. Are you saying I got it right when I guessed what you were *really* after was a *passive* construction? I never explicitly said anything about using those compound nouns *global economic situation* and *business optimization methods*, but I hope you see how little tricks like that can help reduce the need for prepositions that just add syntactic complexity without increasing "readability".

Comment: @ FumbleFingers The only explanation of why I had "dummy" it in mind is that I am not fluent in English. Weird phrases sometimes come to my mind when I try to write on a specialized topic such as economics, corporate finance, etc. :) You got it right, indeed. I was after the passive construction. You simplified the expressions, for what I am very grateful.

Comment: If my answer works for you, you're supposed to upvote and/or accept it. But many people prefer that you wait a day or two before accepting any answer, to allow time for a potentially even better answer to be posted (though you can always switch your acceptance to a different answer later if you want).

Answer (score 0):

I could only come up with:

> This (**it**) is *fueling* a search for business optimization methods".

The construction you're referring to ("*it is snowing*") uses the so-called "[dummy pronoun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dummy_pronoun)" it.

But in my sentence, **it** is not a dummy pronoun, it refers back to the first sentence describing the global economic situation.